# Imports Not Being Used in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin, anko

For some reason non-Android imports aren't working in this Kotlin class that I have. They work in other classes with onCreate methods, but not this adapter class. Is the issue that I don't have an onCreate method in this class? I'm trying to use "import org.jetbrains.anko.*", but it doesn't work.

```
package com.example.christophrrb.firebasetest

import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import org.jetbrains.anko.*

/**
 * Created by Owner on 11/10/2017.
 */
class ViewPeople : AppCompatActivity() {
var peopleList: MutableList<Person> = mutableListOf() //This list stores all of the database value entries.
val ref: DatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("people")

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.view_people)

    ref.addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener {
        //Once you get into these functions, p0 is your new variable that you're working with.
        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError?) {
            alert("There was an error connecting to the database. Try checking your connection.")
        }

        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot?) {
            //ref contains everything in the database node.
            peopleList.clear() //This clears the list so when new data comes up, it doesn't keep the old data in the list.

            if (p0!!.exists()) { //This means basically "if some data exits on the database.
                for(p in p0.children) {
                    val person = p.getValue(Person::class.java) //The getValue method takes a Java class.
                    peopleList.add(person!!);
                }

                //This connects to the layout class.
                val adapter = PeopleAdapter(this@ViewPeople, R.layout.people, peopleList)
                listView.adapter = adapter
            }
        }
    })
}
}
```

Comment: `but it doesn't work` - what happens? Any errors?

Comment: I'll get an error because if I type in something that needs to use that import, the import stays grayed out at the top and what I typed will bring up an error that what I typed in is an unresolved reference.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the correct imports? Just remove the import line and click Alt + Enter on the places where it shows error